# How can return invalid if user input is 2 decimal places? java

Tags: java, double, pattern-matching

I'm new to programming.
I have been trying to return invalid if the user inputs are numbers other than numbers in the format of #.00.

my code is similar to the following

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Twodec{
public static void main (String[] args){
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

String abc = input.next();

double n1 = Double.parseDouble(abc);
double n2 = n1%1;
DecimalFormat twoDPattern = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
int n1length = (twoDPattern.format(n2).length()-1);

if (n1length != 2){
System.out.println("Invalid");
}
}
}
```

However, the if statement seems to be ignored for some reason. if I input 21 or 23.324. It doesn't return invalid.

Answer (score 0):

When you think about formats of data, you should think about their textual representation.  This is fundamentally a `String` operation.

```
boolean hasTwoDigits = abc.matches("\\d+\\.\\d{2}");
```

In terms of the `double` value `0.21e2`, `21`, `21.0` , `21.00` and `21.000` all turn into the same internal representation, and there is no way to tell them apart once you have converted it into a `double` as the information bout how it was entered has been lost.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are complicateing yourself to much...

try checking the decimal part by findind/splitting to a dot or comma,
then validate the lenght of the 2nd part of the array..

## Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        String abc = input.nextLine();
        String[] decimalIntArray = abc.split("\\.");

        if (decimalIntArray.length != 2) {
            System.out.println("Invalid input.. no decimal part");
        } else if (decimalIntArray[1].length() != 2) {
            System.out.println("Invalid input... there is a decimal part but to long or short...");
        } else {
            System.out.println("THIS IS A VALID INPUT!!!");
        }
    }
```